# VPN configuration box is grayed out, Xubuntu Desktop

Tags: networking, virtualbox, xubuntu, network-manager, vpn

I am facing a issue where when I try to add a VPN connection, the VPN configuration Box is grayed out and unclickable (attach in image).

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu server and overthat I had installed Xubuntu desktop.

these are the commands I used to install IPsec VPN

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp  network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

So far I had tried to manage the VPN connection using

```
nm-connection-editor
```

But the issue still remains the same.

Enviroment Knowledge:
Ubuntu-server is installed on VirtualBox

[image]